# "Class XXX is not a valid entity or mapped super class" after moving the class in the filesystem

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I had an entity class in Aib\PlatformBundle\Entity\User.php

I had no problems trying to create its form class through

> php app/ console doctrine:generate:form AibPlatformBundle:User

Now I have change the namespace to Aib\PlatformBundle\Entity\Identity\User, but when I try to generate the form with the task I said before
it says:

> "Class Aib\PlatformBundle\Entity\User is not a valid entity or mapped
>   super class."

This is the file content:

```
<?php
namespace Aib\PlatformBundle\Entity\Identity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * Aib\PlatformBundle\Entity\Identity\User
     *
     * @ORM\Table()
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Aib\PlatformBundle\Entity\Identity
    \UserRepository")
     */
    class User
    {
    ...
```

Any idea?

symfony2.0.4

Comment: Do you have any classes extending User for which you forgot to update namespaces?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to define subnamespaces for your entities, since Symfony will always try to resolve **AibPlatformBundle:User** to **Aim\PlatformBundle\Entity\User**, regardless of its namespace.

Answer (score 273):

Had this problem - don't forget the annotation `* @ORM\Entity` like below:

```
/**
 * Powma\ServiceBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
```

Answer (score 17):

Had this problem yesterday and found this thread. I created the entity with the mapping in a new bundle (e.g. MyFooBundle/Entity/User.php), did all the configuration according to the docs but got the same error from above when trying to load the app.

In the end I realized that I wasn't loading MyFooBundle in AppKernel:

```
new My\FooBundle\MyFooBundle()
```

A great way to debug this is to run this command:

```
app/console doctrine:mapping:info
```

Answer (score 13):

Do check your config.yml file, should be containing something like this:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        # auto_mapping: true
        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings:
                    FOSUserBundle: ~
                    # ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
                    YourUserBundle: ~
                    SonataUserBundle: ~
```

Add your own bundle to the mappings list.

Comment: Cheers!! My config (from Sonata) just had mappings: ~, not specifying any bundles.. Adding them manually fixed my issue :)

Answer (score 12):

I resolved this issue by setting `$useSimpleAnnotationReader=false` when creating the `MetaDataConfiguration`.

Answer (score 11):

I solved this by passing `false` as the second parameter to `Doctrine\ORM\Configuration::newDefaultAnnotationDriver`.

It took me a while of digging through Google and source code.

My case was sort of special since I was using a mapping pointing to another directory unrelated to the Symfony installation as I also had to use legacy code.

I had refactored legacy entities and they stopped working. They used to use `@Annotation` instead of `@ORM\Annotation`, so after refactoring it simply failed to read the metadata. By not using a simple annotation reader, everything seems to be okayish.

Answer (score 9):

In my case the problem was solved by changing my servers cache from **eAccelerator** to **APC**.
Apparently eAccelerator strips all the comments from files which breaks your annotations.

Comment: Opcache has a setting to disable the comment stripping `opcache.save_comments=1`, maybe there is one too for eAccelerator/APC?

Answer (score 9):

big thx to Mark Fu and mogoman

I knew it had to be somewhere in the config.yml... and being able to test it against the

```
app/console doctrine:mapping:info
```

really helped!

In fact, this command just simply stops at an error... no feedback, but when everything is fine you should be able to see all your entities listed.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the same exception by deleting a conflicting autogenerated orm.php file in the bundle's Resources/config/doctrine folder; according to the documentation: "A bundle can accept only one metadata definition format. For example, it's not possible to mix YAML metadata definitions with annotated PHP entity class definitions."

Comment: Thank you. You saved me a lot of time. Got this error after creating a Entity php-formatted, than deleted it and created a new annotated entity with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Very high possibility that you have PHP 5.3.16 (Symfony 2.x will not work with it). Anyway you should load check page on http://you.site.name/config.php 
If you had project not worked on hosting server, next lines must be removed in "config.php":

```
if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
    '127.0.0.1',
    '::1',
))) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('This script is only accessible from localhost.');
}
```

Goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

1. Entity must have proper Entity and Table annotations (order may matter so try both)
2. If there is custom repository it MUST be accessed via Entity class itself ($entityManager->getRepository('your ENTITY class name')), as calling it via Repository class name will trick Doctrine into thinking Repo class must be an entity itself. Silly, but Doctrine does not make hard distinction.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was I was doing

```
$em->getRepository(EntityRepository::class)
```

instead of

```
$em->getRepository(Entity::class)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i was migrating to the PHP annotations but still had this

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
```

Removing it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was too zealous during a refactor and had deleted a doctrine yml file!

Answer (score 0):

In my case on my mac I was using src/MainBundle/Resource/Config/Doctrine, of course it worked on Mac but it didn't work on production Ubuntu server. Once renamed Config to config and Doctrine to doctrine, the mapping files were found and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case after making make:entity  i tried   the following command

`php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" annotation --path=src/Entity`
which generates the entity from the database
However, this Command don t provide the getters and setters that will cause you unknown method error (getId for example) if you are using it inside a controller or you ll use it later So i decided to go back to the generated entity from the

```
php bin/console make:entity
```

so i can bring back the missing methods but unfortunately this caused me the error class is not a valid entity or mapped superclass.
next to prevent this error i haven 't patience to read this documentation

[1]: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/tutorials/override-field-association-mappings-in-subclasses.html#override-field-association-mappings-in-subclasses especially i m using attributes in the place of annotation,
therefore i brought back the generated entity and just adding the following command which generates getters and setters `$ php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App`
saved my life ,though this solved my problem but i didn t figure out why in the first case it caused me the error of this topic

Answer (score -2):

I got rid of the same error message as in your case by using app/console_dev instead of just app/console

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it