# How to solve Class xxx is not a valid entity or mapped super class error

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, entity

I have defined a class Setting like this:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/** @ORM\Entity */
class Setting {
    /** @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *  @ORM\GeneratedValue
     *  @ORM\id
     */
    private $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(length=255, nullable=true) */
    private $displayname;

    /** @ORM\Column(length=255) */
    private $name;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="text") */
    private $value;

    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->$name;
    }

    public function __set($key, $value){
        $this->$key = $value;
    }

    public function getFullName() {
        return $this->name . ' suffix';
    }


    public static function getValue($settingName) {
        $result = '';
        try {
            $setting = em()->createQuery('SELECT s FROM Setting s WHERE s.name = :name')
                ->setParameter('name', $settingName)
                ->getSingleResult();

            $result = $setting->value;
        }
        catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $exception) {

        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this gives an error Fatal error: `Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'Class "Setting" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.' in xxxxx/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php on line 216`

How can this be solved?

Comment: in what namespace and folder is the entity? check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820597/class-xxx-is-not-a-valid-entity-or-mapped-super-class-after-moving-the-class-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution: it seems that the problem lies with the use of SimpleAnnotationReader.

When configurating the annotationDriver like this (second parameter should be false) it works.

```
$driver = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/models', false
);
```

Comment: in what file do you write that ?

Answer (score 3):

To solve this problem I had to call [Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.Tools.Setup.html) with false in the last parameter to avoid the use of SimpleAnnotationReader because you need AnnotationReader to use the ORM\ namespace prefix.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

$dbParams = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => '', 
    'dbname' => 'db',
);

$path = __DIR__ . '/Entity';

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array($path), true, null, null, false);

$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```