# Symfony2 Class Brenne\BaseBundle\Entity\Websites is not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I do have a really weird problem and searched&tried different approaches. As my title states my Entities (with all of them!) are not working - mean their cant mapped.

Ill come fast to the point:

**Extension Array**

```
Array ( [0] => Core [1] => date [2] => ereg [3] => libxml [4] => openssl [5] => pcre [6] => sqlite3 [7] => zlib [8] => bcmath [9] => bz2 [10] => calendar [11] => ctype [12] => curl [13] => dba [14] => dom [15] => hash [16] => fileinfo [17] => filter [18] => ftp [19] => gd [20] => gettext [21] => gmp [22] => SPL [23] => iconv [24] => session [25] => intl [26] => json [27] => ldap [28] => mbstring [29] => mcrypt [30] => mssql [31] => mysql [32] => standard [33] => PDO [34] => pdo_dblib [35] => mysqlnd [36] => pdo_sqlite [37] => pgsql [38] => apc [39] => posix [40] => Reflection [41] => imap [42] => shmop [43] => SimpleXML [44] => snmp [45] => soap [46] => sockets [47] => pdo_mysql [48] => exif [49] => sysvmsg [50] => sysvsem [51] => sysvshm [52] => tidy [53] => tokenizer [54] => wddx [55] => xml [56] => xmlreader [57] => xmlrpc [58] => xmlwriter [59] => xsl [60] => zip [61] => mysqli [62] => apache2handler [63] => Phar [64] => mhash )
```

So far with I came up with and tried to fix:

1. APC on (no eAcc which mostly caused the problem) REF:(["Class XXX is not a valid entity or mapped super class" after moving the class in the filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820597/class-xxx-is-not-a-valid-entity-or-mapped-super-class-after-moving-the-class-i))
2. Delete the Doctrine Folder in Resources, cleared the cache. No sucess.
3. Addded full namespaces to the config ORM's entity // change: "company" to "x/basebundle/entity/company" doesn't worked so reverted changes.
4. I Do no use annoations, Iam using yml.
5. Auto Mapping is true!

`Resources/Config/Doctrine/Websites.orm.yml` takes the entity class as first argument:

```
Brenne\BaseBundle\Entity\Website:
    type: entity
    table: website
    repositoryClass: Brenne\BaseBundle\Repository\WebsiteRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 110
            nullable: true
        url:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: true
        logo:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: true
        description:
            type: text
    oneToMany:
        assignedPing:
            targetEntity: ping
            mappedBy: website
    manyToOne:
        company:
          targetEntity: Company
          inversedBy: website
```

---

`/Entity/Websites.orm.yml` takes the entity class as first argument:

```
<?php

namespace Brenne\BaseBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Website
 */
class Website
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $logo;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    private $assignedPing;

    /**
     * @var \Brenne\BaseBundle\Entity\Company
     */
    private $company;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->assignedPing = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Website
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set url
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @return Website
     */
    public function setUrl($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get url
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->url;
    }

    /**
     * Set logo
     *
     * @param string $logo
     * @return Website
     */
    public function setLogo($logo)
    {
        $this->logo = $logo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get logo
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLogo()
    {
        return $this->logo;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Website
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Add assignedPing
     *
     * @param \Brenne\BaseBundle\Entity\ping $assignedPing
     * @return Website
     */
    public function addAssignedPing(\Brenne\BaseBundle\Entity\ping $assignedPing)
    {
        $this->assignedPing[] = $assignedPing;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove assignedPing
     *
     * @param \Brenne\BaseBundle\Entity\ping $assignedPing
     */
    public function removeAssignedPing(\Brenne\BaseBundle\Entity\ping $assignedPing)
    {
        $this->assignedPing->removeElement($assignedPing);
    }

    /**
     * Get assignedPing
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getAssignedPing()
    {
        return $this->assignedPing;
    }

    /**
     * Set company
     *
     * @param \Brenne\BaseBundle\Entity\Company $company
     * @return Website
     */
    public function setCompany(\Brenne\BaseBundle\Entity\Company $company = null)
    {
        $this->company = $company;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get company
     *
     * @return \Brenne\BaseBundle\Entity\Company 
     */
    public function getCompany()
    {
        return $this->company;
    }
}
```

---

I dont know anyhting else to do, may you come up with an idea! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to name the mapping files and folders where you store them
**exactly** as per convention.

... Otherwise you'll face invalid mapping classmetadata or errors when loading the files.

Keep in mind that files and folders are **case sensitive** on some systems.

**Solution:**

The mapping file should be read:

- `Website.orm.yml`
- ... or ...
- `Brenne.BaseBundle.Entity.Website.orm.yml`

and it should live in the folder ...

```
src/Brenne/BaseBundle/Resources/config/doctrine
```

Please be careful with the naming ( `config`, `doctrine` - small caps, `Website` without **s** )...

---

clear your symfony cache for the correct environment (`app/console ca:c --env=..` or `rm -rf app/cache/*`) and restart your webserver / fpm-pool (in order to clear cached metadata from APC and opcache )

Comment: This worked for me. It seems really important, first that you don't have `Invalid Entities` and second taking care of case sensitive file/folders as the wrong small caps on `ping`@oneToMany Website broke it. So **take care** of **case sensitive** files/folders!

Comment: i'm glad you were able to resolve your issue :) thanks for reporting back.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `\` in front of namespace:

```
\Brenne\BaseBundle\Entity\Websites:
type: entity
table: websites
repositoryClass: \Brenne\BaseBundle\Repository\WebsitesRepository
```

Comment: Didn't helped in this case. However if I added \ infront of the namespace it stopped working at my local machine (Windows Xampp).

Anyhow the error (with and without \) is the same on the production server.

Comment: Just discovered: I do have 3 invalid entties on my localhost. Could this be a problem? Dunno how to fix them to be honest.

More or less are all the same like this:

`Brenne\BaseBundle\Entity\Company 
The association Brenne\BaseBundle\Entity\Company#status refers to the owning side field Brenne\BaseBundle\Entity\Websites#website which does not exist.`

Comment: probably problem in it

Comment: You need `mappedBy: company` in your `Company` mapping and `inversedBy: website` in your `Website` mapping. owning and inverse side are concepts of doctrine and might not always reflect what comes to your mind if you think like Company owns website or other way around ... `inversedBy` is always the owning side.

Comment: Yea exactly. I did find that by myself after reading the Doctrine documentation and fixxed it. You're completely right regarding mappedBy/inveresdBy. For ref: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html

Answer (score 0):

If this is *really* the content of your `Websites.orm.yml` file, then the indentation is wrong:

You should indent right after `Brenne\BaseBundle\Entity\Websites:` like so:

```
Brenne\BaseBundle\Entity\Websites:
    type: entity
    table: websites
    repositoryClass: Brenne\BaseBundle\Repository\WebsitesRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 110
            nullable: true
        url:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: true
        url:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: true
        description:
            type: text
    manyToOne:
        company:
            targetEntity: Company
            inversedBy: websites
            joinColumn:
                name: company_id
                referencedCo
```

Comment: Hey, no the indentation was there. I just struggle a bit with the stackoverflow editor there. As mentioned on the other answer I had some entities errors which I fixed now.

I edited the correct Website.orm.yml back into the first question. Thanks for your time!