# Class "AppBundle\Entity\Organization" is not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I want to visualize data from a database with Doctrine, but it doesn't seems to work...

Here's my class `Organization`:

```
<?php
 namespace AppBundle\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**Class Organization
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="organization")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\
 * OrganizationRepository")
 *
 */
 class Organization
 {

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;


/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=45)
 *
 */
protected $name;




/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param int $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * @param string $name
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
}
```

}

Here's the error:

> Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: Class
>   "AppBundle\Entity\Organization" is not a valid entity or mapped super
>   class.
>
> at
>   vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php:346 
>   at
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException::classIsNotAValidEntityOrMappedSuperClass('AppBundle\Entity\Organization')
>        (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php:91)
>   at
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver->loadMetadataForClass('AppBundle\Entity\Organization',
>   object(ClassMetadata))
>        (vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/MappingDriverChain.php:102)
>   at
>   Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain->loadMetadataForClass('AppBundle\Entity\Organization',
>   object(ClassMetadata))
>        (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:151)
>   at
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadMetadata(object(ClassMetadata),
>   null, false, array())
>        (vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:332)
>   at
>   Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata('AppBundle\Entity\Organization')
>        (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:78)
>   at
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata('AppBundle\Entity\Organization')
>        (vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:216)
>   at
>   Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor('AppBundle:Organization')
>        (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:281)   at Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getClassMetadata('AppBundle:Organization')
>        (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php:44)
>   at
>   Doctrine\ORM\Repository\DefaultRepositoryFactory->getRepository(object(EntityManager),
>   'AppBundle:Organization')
>        (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:698)   at Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:Organization')
>        (src/AppBundle/Controller/OrganizationController.php:27)   at AppBundle\Controller\OrganizationController->showInfoAction()   at
>   call_user_func_array(array(object(OrganizationController),
>   'showInfoAction'), array())
>        (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:153)
>   at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request),
>   1)
>        (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:68)
>   at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1,
>   true)
>        (vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:171)
>   at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
>        (web/app_dev.php:29)

I have the `OrganizationController` and the `OrganizationRepository`.

Comment: In entity annotations after `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass` you have line break and that might be the reason.

Comment: @TomaszTurkowski That is because StackOverflow had some problems to put the complete line without breaking it, but in my code it's okey.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Class XXX is not a valid entity or mapped super class" after moving the class in the filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820597/class-xxx-is-not-a-valid-entity-or-mapped-super-class-after-moving-the-class-i)

Comment: @Vamsi I saw this link but didn't work... :(

Comment: 1-. Which version of php and Symfony are you using? 2.- Try a php app/console doctrine:mapping:info and see if it clears something. 3.- Try a php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata 4.- Try a php app/console cache:clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move class name annotation to next line or give space before it as below

```
/**
 * Class Organization
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="organization")
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\OrganizationRepository")
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should check the php file name. Does you entity filename is Organization.php
2. You should remove `setId()` method in your code (It won't resolve your problem, but you mustn't put this method). Because `$id` is auto generated.

Remove this:

```
 /**
  * @param int $id
  */
  public function setId($id)
  {
       $this->id = $id;
  }
```

3. Also - try not to use the private visibility for the `$id` property. Right way is - set it as protected.